# Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type - Is there any workaround the fact that pkg_resources are not supported by pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.6, pyinstaller, pkg-resources

I'm new to pyinstaller and I'm getting this error (NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type) when I try to import a file with my App.

The complete traceback is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
  File "BioRank.py", line 190, in load
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 710, in style
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\tizma\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 111, in Styler
  File "site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
  File "site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
  File "site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 113, in load
  File "site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 234, in get_source
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1396, in has_resource
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1449, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
```

I did some research and found out that pyinstaller does not support pkg_resources. Is there any workaround this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem using **pyinstaller**. The solution was to edit `your-python-path\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\stytle`:
Go to line **120** and change

```
template = env.**get_template**("html.tpl")
```

to

```
template = env.**from_string**("html.tpl")
```

Then try again.
My problem was I was using background color in `pd.Series("backgroud....)` and the pyinstaller was not building it, so after the change it works.

Comment: It raises an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io.formats.style'`

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the exact same issue with pyinstaller not including pkg_resources. Rafael's answer above sorted it out for me. Much simpler than the other solutions I found related to this issue. I needed to edit the style.py file. This solution also doesn't require any additional datas in the spec file which is convenient.

Path:

```
your_path\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py
```

Before:

```
template = env.get_template("html.tpl")
```

After:

```
template = env.from_string("html.tpl")
```

Comment: Life saver and by far the best answer after an hour or scouring SO.